# Tortoise SVN 1.6 externals single file

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, externals

I have a scenario where i want to get documentation files from Documentation folder in SVN, and the pdf version only. Current the documentation folder has .doc and .pdf files

The target folder is Portal/Docs

I setup a svn:externals property on Portal/docs to
svn:externals /svn/codebase/Documentation/Release Notes.pdf

on current checkout directory of
/svn/codebase/Portal/Docs C:\Portal\Docs

I receive an error saying
'http://codebase/Documentation/Release'
at revision X doesn't exist

I have tried %20, "", + and ? but does not work...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Should retitle to 'spaces in external', since your problem is with the spaces (not with the single file external)

Comment: This may have changed in later versions, but I thought externals references could not contain spaces in Tortoise SVN..presumably for this very reason?

Comment: It used to be impossible. Supposedly, it was fixed as of SVN 1.6: http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=2461

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `file://` protocol to access the external, which will allow you to use `%20`:

```
svn:externals file:///svn/codebase/Documentation/Release%20Notes.pdf "Release Notes.pdf"
```

You can also use a repository-absolute path:

```
svn:externals ^/Documentation/Release%20Notes.pdf "Release Notes.pdf"
```

assuming that your repository is in /svn/codebase.

Incidentally, you should always use version-pinning for your externals (appending `@<revision-number>` to the external URL), as file/folder properties are versioned. Version pinning guarantees that an older checkout of your source tree gives you the externals as they appeared at the time, rather than the newest copy of the externals.

Comment: getting invalid url with file:///

Comment: had to get rid of **file:///**
so 
`svn/codebase/Documentation/Release%20Notes.pdf "Release Notes.pdf"`
did the trick